# Random Fullscreen Video Background on Load (jsfiddle included)

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, random

Trying to get my site to display a random fullscreen background video from a folder of videos I will maintain. I'd like to keep adding to the folder (bg1.mp4, bg2.mp4, etc...) and have the code automatically choose a random video to loop when you load the page.

here is my current code: https://jsfiddle.net/nenr3kyn/2/ , which isn't fully functional. I have a specific video chosen as the source file:

```
<source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

because I can't seem to get the html to call the variable set by the javascript "vid", like this:

```
<source src=vid type="video/mp4">
```

Also, this code wouldn't allow me to simply add files to the folder, and is limiting me to the videos that are specifically listed in the code. I'd rather have the javascript able to count all the files currently in the folder and choose a random, but couldn't get that to work either.

Any ideas?
Any input is greatly appreciated.
Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `loop` attribute it wouldn't trigger the `ended` event.

```
videoPlayer.addEventListener('ended', function(){
       var videoLink = ['link1', 'link2','link3'];
       var nextVid = Math.floor( Math.random() * videoLink.length);
       this.src = videoLink[nextVideo];
       this.play();
    });
```

Hope this will help